# On the delocalization of simple random walk

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, random-variables, random-walk

Let $\tau_1$, $\tau_2$ be two nonnegative integer valued random variables such that 
$P( \tau_1 > r) \leq P( \tau_2 > r)$ for any $r \geq 0$, let $X(i)$ be a symmetric random walk on $\mathbb{Z}$ starting from the origin which is independent from $\tau_1, \tau_2$.

How to prove that 
$$
P( | X( \tau_1 )| \geq r ) \leq P( | X( \tau_2 )| \geq r )
$$
for any $r \geq 0$? Namely, if we wait longer time, the random walk is less localized around its starting point.

Comment: You can write down the PMF of $X(t)$ and integrate it in $t$ over the distribution of the $\tau_i$. I think it should be fairly straightforward, seeing as $X(i)$ is just $i-\mathrm{Bin}(2i,1/2)$ distributed.